# Cascading dropdown in sharepoint list

Tags: custom-list, cascading

Want to create cascading dropdown in SharePoint.
I have created 2 list department and employee and matched item using lookup.
Department has 6 items and employees has 70 items.

So, how to create dropdown list for these two columns?

Comment: you can use SPCascadeDropdowns javascript function to do the operation kindly go through the following link [cascading dropdown code plex](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPServices to achieve this:

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
  relationshipWebURL: "",
  relationshipList: "",
  relationshipListParentColumn: "",
  relationshipListChildColumn: "",
  relationshipListSortColumn: "",
  parentColumn: "",
  childColumn: "",
  CAMLQuery: "",
  CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions>   <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns></QueryOptions>",
  listName: $().SPServices.SPListNameFromUrl(), 
  promptText: "",
  simpleChild: false,           // Added in v0.6.2
  selectSingleOption: false,        // Added in v0.6.2
  matchOnId: false,         // Added in v0.7.1
  completefunc: null,
  debug: false
});
```

Comment: This is the easiest way of all the ways! I've tried several other solutions and spservices is the easiest.  Here is the demo: http://www.sympraxisconsulting.com/Demos/Demo Pages/CascadingDropdowns.aspx